# Replacing text with varying letter case

Tags: javascript, string, text

Here's my code:

```
let replaced = name.replace(search, '"' + search + '"');
```

so if I have name `Robert` and I'm searching for `obe` I will see `R"obe"rt`, if I search for `"Rob"` I will see `"Rob"ert`, but if I search for `'rob'` I got nothing, and I want to have `"Rob"ert`

How can I fix that?

Comment: add a live example please that reproduce your bug

Comment: Use regex to make the match case-insensitive. `name.replace(new RegExp(search, 'i'), '"$&"')`

Comment: If `search` contains special characters: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/2025923